Max amount of entries in n dimensional unit ball of infinity norm, question on YiLei Chen's eprint555 Lemma 3.10 proof
On pages 23-24 of YiLei Chen's paper "Quantum Algorithms for Lattice Problems", he claims the following state's support contains at most $ 2r\log n $ entries:
$$
\left|\varphi_{1}\right\rangle=\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}, k \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y} \in(r \log n) \mathcal{B}_{\infty}^{n}} \exp \left(-\pi\left(\frac{1}{r^{2}}+\frac{i}{s^{2}}\right)\|k \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\|^{2}\right)|k \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\rangle
$$
Wouldn't it actually contain $ (2r\log n)^{n} $ entries? This is quoting the paper:
We have $ \|\varphi_{1}\|_{2}^{2}\ \leq 2r\log n \in poly(n)$ since there are at most $ 2r\log n $ entries in the support.
What am I missing here?

You're interested in finding all the $k$ for which $k\mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}$ has all its entries within $(-r\log(n),r\log(n))$.
Let us consider any entry $i$. The number of $k$ such that $kx_i-y_i$ is within the desired bounds is at most $2r\log(n)$. We can first compute it for $y_i=0$, which is immediate, and then adding a $y_i$ simply "shifts" the interval.
But now, I assume that your reasoning was "we can choose $n$ such indices and we have at most $2r\log(n)$ choices for each of them", which led you to this $\left(2r\log(n)\right)^n$ upper bound. But the relation must not be valid for any entry, but for all. That is, denote $\left[\ell_i,L_i\right]$ the interval for which, if $k\in\left[\ell_i,L_i\right]$, then $kx_i-y_i$ is within the desired bounds. Since all entries must be within the desired bounds, the final set you're interested in is:
$$\bigcap_i\left[\ell_i,L_i\right]\,.$$
In particular, its size is upper-bounded by the size of any of these intervals, which is itself upper-bounded by $2r\log(n)$.
